# How to read jpeg files in R one by one using loop?

Tags: r, image-processing, deep-learning

I have jpeg files in my local directory, I want to Extract text from all the images one by one and should record all the values in each cells accordingly . Can anyone please help me with the code?  I have used Tesseract apnd Magick package to extract the text. But now I need to keep it in the loop

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to know which files you want to read. Go to the directory where they are located and get their names with `list.files`.

```
old_dir <- getwd()
setwd('path/to/directory')
filenames <- list.files(pattern = '\\.jpg')  # or '\\.jpeg'
```

Now the standard trick is to loop through the file names with one of the `*apply` functions. For the sake of simplicity, I will define a function that do the actual read and OCR text extraction operations.

```
library(magick)
library(tesseract)

read_ocr_png <- function(file){
  img <- image_read(file)
  image_ocr(img)
}

text_list <- lapply(filenames, read_ocr_png)
names(text_list) <- filenames
```

And reset the working directory when done.

```
setwd(old_dir)
```